# Laravel authenticating user suddenly not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, controller

suddenly my login isn't working, can't authenticate my user but if I register a new user it logs-in authomatic I just changed the routes but still can't make it work if i rollback.

Routes.php:

```
//pagina inicial
Route::get('/', 'PublicController@welcome');

//hilos
Route::get('/seccion/{subboaName}', 'ThreadController@index');
Route::post('/seccion/{subboaName}', 'ThreadController@store');
Route::get('/thread/{img}', 'ThreadController@mostrarImagen');

//Invitaciones
Route::get('/administrar/invitaciones', 'invitacionController@index');
Route::get('/administrar/invitacion/{id}', 'invitacionController@mostrarInvitacion');
Route::delete('/administrar/invitacion/{id}', 'invitacionController@eliminarInvitacion');
Route::post('/administrar/invitacion', 'invitacionController@invitacion');

//Secciones
Route::get('/administrar/secciones', 'BoardController@index');
Route::get('/administrar/seccion/{id}', 'BoardController@mostrarSeccion');
Route::delete('/administrar/seccion/{id}', 'BoardController@eliminarSeccion');
Route::post('/administrar/secciones', 'BoardController@seccion');

//Subsecciones
Route::get('/administrar/subsecciones', 'SubboardController@index');
Route::get('/administrar/subseccion/{id}', 'SubboardController@mostrarSubseccion');
Route::delete('/administrar/subseccion/{id}', 'SubboardController@eliminarSubseccion');
Route::post('/administrar/subsecciones', 'SubboardController@subseccion');

//usuarios
Route::auth();
```

Middleware/Authenticate.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('ingresar');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

login.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Ingresar</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form col-md-12 center-block" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/ingresar') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
                            @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                <p class="help-block">
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                      <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                                      {{ $errors->first('name') }}
                                    </div>
                                </p>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Contraseña" name="password">
                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <p class="help-block">
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                      <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                                      {{ $errors->first('password') }}
                                    </div>
                                </p>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Recordarme
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">
                                    Ingresar
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-center">
                            <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">¿Has olvidado tu contraseña?</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

AuthController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Invite;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:25|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users|exists:invites',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:6',
            'invite' => 'required|exists:invites,code',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        Invite::where('email', $data['email'])->delete();
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:

```
public function auth()
{
    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('ingresar', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    $this->post('ingresar', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
    $this->get('salir', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    $this->get('registrar', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    $this->post('registrar', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    $this->get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
    $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
}
```

Comment: What version of Laravel do you use?

Comment: I just updated it to 5.2.39

Comment: Previous version was also 5.2?

Comment: Yes it was a 5.2.XX can't remember wich version exactly

Comment: take a look at upgrading guide : [upgrade laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0)

Comment: there is no upgrading to 5.2.xx to 5.2.xx

Comment: Why are you writing stuff inside vendor directory?

Comment: I'm not writing anything, in laravel 5 > you have a shortcut called Route:auth() and it's stored on vendor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, by default laravel try to compare an email not a name, so when I updated laravel my files got overwritted and wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

I had also the same issue. When i restart the Apache it worked.Please restart Apache before looking into code.